# Can anyone tell me why I get this 'ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1' message from GitLab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

Every time I push to GitLab, even on a brand new app that has no changes to it I get the following email:

```
Subject:
 appname | Pipeline #xxxxxx has failed for master | xxxxxx

Content:
----------
 Primary key fingerprint: 

GPG signature looks good

Extracting to ~/.yarn...

Adding to $PATH... We've added the following to your /root/.bashrc

If this isn't the profile of your current shell then please add the following to your correct profile:

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

Successfully installed Yarn 1.22.4! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.

$ export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

$ node -v

v10.15.2

$ yarn -v

1.22.4

$ ruby -v

ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision xxxxxxxx) [x86_64-linux]

$ which ruby

/usr/local/bin/ruby

$ gem install bundler --no-document

Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4

1 gem installed

$ bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}" --path /cache
[DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set path '/cache'`, and stop using this flag

Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.6.5

Running after_script

Uploading artifacts for failed job

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

...
```

There are some posts about Docker problems but I'm not running Docker. This happens on a brand new `rails new appname` file push. I've contacted GitLab about it and they have never responded. Also, this email says I am running Ruby version 2.7.0, which is NOT the case. I run 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> email says I am running Ruby version 2.7.0, which is NOT the case. I run 2.6.5.

Logs clearly show that job executor uses Ruby 2.7

```sh
$ ruby -v

ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision xxxxxxxx) [x86_64-linux]
```

From what you posted we can only see `` [DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag ... `` and different Ruby version.

I'd suggest investigating full logs on GitLab pipelines page (mails can contain truncated content). Also if this is your custom runner you could connect to it and execute commands step by step to see what command ends with error.